# Using both PCA and Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, pca, dimensionality-reduction

Is it standard practice to use PCA before using Logistic Regression? Or is it considered to be non advisable?

Comment: It’s perhaps not standard but certainly can be fine...depending on what you want to do. So what do you want to do with your logistic regression?